# Separating code between angular services and controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have read that we should separate the code between `controllers` and `services`.

I have done like this , i am not sure if its right, but it looks like i am repeating some stuff.

this is my service

```
            getUsers: function () {
                return Restangular.all('loc').all('users').

            },
```

and this is in my controller

```
    // controller
    var getUsers = function() {        
                userService.getUsers().getList().then(function (users) {
                $scope.users = users;
            }function (error) {
                $scope.errors = error.data;
            }); }

    getUsers();
```

I want to know that whats the point of using service becauise i still have to do all stuff in controller.

Ideally i would just like to get users straight to scope all from service.

I want to know that am i using it wrong??

Comment: The service would allow you to pass the data between controllers. Yes you will still have to call the service logic from the controller, but if you app gets larger, you will need to pass that data around. This is what the service is for.

Comment: Here is link where you can understand why we need services? http://blog.pluralsight.com/angularjs-step-by-step-services

Answer (score 0):

Typically you do this so that you can Mock your Service for your Controller Unit tests.  For example a Service would be used to interact with your Database.  By doing this you can Mock the Database and write Unit Tests for the Controller without interacting with the Database.

You might also be using the Service in more then one Controller.